# Filtering on centroid distance between layers in Rule based layer styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology, centroids, rule-based

By using *Rule based layer styling* for a polygon shapefile I want to display only those features whose centroid is separated by 1.000m from the feature centroids of another polygon layer ('layerB'). The following filter expression is invalid and I cannot understand why:

```
distance(centroid($geometry), centroid(geometry('layerB_011018_5154ef48_b1da_43ae_91b9_daeb20f6cab9'))) > 1000
```

Getting the feature geometries from 'layerB' is probably the problem here. The `geometry` operator doesn't seem to fetch all feature geometries from a 'layerB'. How can I solve this?

Comment: The functions `geometry()` has one argument: it expects a feature as input. However, you set a layer as input. that cannot work. Honestly I don't quite understand how your solution should look like: can you post a screenshot? Rule based style on layer A if distance to **which centroid(s)** of layer B? All of them? The closest one?

Comment: I want to style the features in layer A depending on whether the feature-centroid is within or beyond a 1.000m from any feature's centroid in layer B. Hope that's more concise :-) In any case, thanks for elaborating on `geometry()`, that wasn't clear to me yet.

Comment: See the help in the expression string builder - when you click on a function (like `geometry()`) in the middle, on the right side you see the help where you see exactly what kind of input (arguments) the functions expects. By the way: Make it clear if you still look for an answer or if the answer by @MrXsquared solved your problem (by accepting it). If not, give some information what you're missing - otherwise, it's difficult to guess. And: any substantial clarification about your problem should be included in the initial question by editing not - not in comments here.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
distance(centroid($geometry), centroid(aggregate('layerB', 'collect', $geometry))) > 1000
```

The `centroid(aggregate())` part does collect all geometries of 'layerB' as a Multi-Geometry and return the centroid this collection (so the whole layer).

The [`centroid()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#centroid) function expects a geometry as input, not a layer nor a feature. And the [`geometry()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#id26) function would expect a feature, as already mentioned by [@Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409505/qgis-rule-based-layer-styling-filter-on-centroid-distance-between-layers/409506#comment666578_409505).

---

To only take the nearest centroid into consideration, you can use [`overlay_nearest()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest) since QGIS 3.16+ the following:

```
distance(centroid($geometry), centroid(overlay_nearest('layerB',$geometry)[0])) > 1000
```

You can also add a `limit:=`, `filter:=` or `max_distance:=` as optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this works in principle, but in my particular context it's not useful to consider layerB as a single multi-geometry. I don't think my idea is going anywhere and I'll abandon this approach. FYI I've used with `get_feature()` successfully in another project, to filter features from layer A laying within _a single feature of layer B_: `within(  $geometry ,  geometry(get_feature( 'layerB','fid', 213)))`.

Comment: @HansRoelofsen if you have QGIS 3.16+ available that would be possible by using `overlay_nearest()`, try my updated answer.